# react-infinite-scroll-component not working properly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, next.js

I've been trying the whole day to set an infinite scrolling lazy load in my MERN stack project, and for it I'm using the react-infinite-scroll-component library.

I've tried fetching events that were previously stored in a mongoDB database and new events seem to appear after scrolling but dissapear immediately.

I've actually set a limitation of 5 events per page in the backend but I don't understand how this affects the lazy loading I'm trying to set on the client side.
Also new events seem to be loading fine in the console so I'm running out of ideas.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code of the component:

```
const TabsInicio = () => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0)
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true)

  const obtenerEventos = async (url) => {
    const response = await clienteAxios.get(url);
    return response.data;
};

const { data: eventosData, error } = useSWR(
    `usuarios/cargar-eventos`,
    obtenerEventos
);
const obtenerMasEventos = async () => {
  try {
    const nextPage = currentPage + 1;
    const response = await clienteAxios.get(`usuarios/cargar-eventos?page=${nextPage}`);
    const newEvents = response.data.eventos;
    if (newEvents.length === 0) {
      setHasMore(false)
    }


    mutate(`usuarios/cargar-eventos`, () => ({
        eventos: [...eventosData.eventos, ...newEvents],
    }));
    console.log(newEvents)
    setCurrentPage(nextPage); // Actualizar la página actual
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
}

  return (
 <div>
                <InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={(currentPage + 1) * 5}
          next={obtenerMasEventos}
          hasMore={hasMore}
          loader={<h4 className='text-white'>Loading...</h4>}
          >
            <div className="mb-4 flex justify-center items-center">

            </div>
            <div className='lg:py-8 md:py-5 lg:pl-10 lg:pr-[72px] flex flex-col lg:gap-8 md:gap-6 gap-4 p-2 rounded'>
               {eventosData ? (
              eventosData.eventos.map((evento, index) => (
                <UsuarioComunidad 
                  key={evento._id}
                  evento={evento}
                  index={index}
                />
              ))
            ) : (
              <div className='h-[50vh] flex justify-center items-center'>
              <Spinner />
          </div>
            )}
            </div>
            </InfiniteScroll>
          </div>
```

And this is the code of the model in the backend:

```
import { UserEvent } from "../models/EventoUsuario.js";

const obtenerEventos = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const page = req.query.page || 0
        const limit = 5

        const eventos = await UserEvent.find({})
            .sort({ timestamp: -1 })
            .skip(page * limit)
            .limit(limit);

        res.status(200).json({ eventos });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Error al obtener los eventos" });
    }
}

export { obtenerEventos }
```

Comment: Just a question, 
Can you get the necessary data from the backend? The array of data.